# Is it OK to use id attribute in component's html?

Tags: html, css, angular6

Consider a component `c` with `html`

```
<form id="someID"[formGroup]="codeEditorForm" novalidate>
</form>
```

with `css`

```
#SomeID{
color:grey;
}
```

If `C` gets included in a parent component `P` two times then wouldn't the `id` get duplicated as well which should not happen in `html`

Question 1 - should I not use `id` in `Angular`?
Question 2 - how shall I then write `css` rules without using `id`?

Comment: You write it via classes. And if you use ID, add some variable to it. `id="someID_{{index}}"`

Comment: got the variable bit. What did you mean by `via classes`? also, if I add add id programatically, how do I write css for it? Is it by using css rules like ^?

Comment: [CSS Class Selectors explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) Angular will scope these to your component. But if you have problems grasping the concept of css classes you should learn these first before you start with angular. (and btw, why angular 6 and not version 9, the current version?)

Comment: Thanks. Working on a personal project out of hobby along with a regular job. Not feeling a need to move to 9 at the moment.

Comment: happy to accept your answer. Got confused between `css`'s class an `angular` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `can` use IDs but generally you don't need to do it.

Angular scopes the styles automatically, so a class defined in one component won't affect a class with the same name in another component.

```
<form id="someID" class="my-form" [formGroup]="codeEditorForm" novalidate>
</form>

.my-form {
  color: green;
}
```

Also note that you should make sure that there is always a space after you define a property. In your posted example there was no space after `someId"` Maybe it doesn't matter in this case but I guess it's better to start looking out for small things like this right away.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are there are two differences between `id` and `class`.

First is that `id` is used for single specific element, while `class` can target multiple elements, this means that you normally would  use `id` selector if you are sure that an element will not be repeated, something like navbar.

And the second one is that `id` selector is more specific than `class` selector, this means that if there are any conflicts of styles,  rules written in `id` selector override rules written in `class` selector

Normally you would not use it to override rules as there is other way to do it, so in order to decide which one to use all you need to do is think about this >> is the element you are giving id to really gonna be unique?

Answer (score 0):

Angular support id on html. But as you are loading multiple times the 'C' component on your 'P' component,so the Id will be duplicated. So better you use class instead of id on your html..

```
<form class="yourClass"[formGroup]="codeEditorForm" novalidate>
</form>
```

On your 'C' component's css,

```
  .yourClass{
    color:grey;
    }
```